# Windows Phone Deserialize to List JSON .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7, deserialization

I have problem deserialize string with JSON.Net on WP7. I have this JSON string:

[JSON Example](http://pastebin.com/cr2m5z2E)

and I have generate from it a class ( http://json2csharp.com/ ).

```
       void GETHotels()
        {
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"..."));
            c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
        }

        DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {         
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Classes.RootObject>>(e.Result);
        }
```

But when I try deserialize e.Result, I get Exception:

> Error converting value "[{"hotId": ... 6390285}]" to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Hotel_cz.Classes.RootObject]'. Path
>   '', line 1, position 971.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: can you show the code for RootObject ?

Comment: public class RootObject
    {
        public int hotId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
var hotels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Hotel>>(e.Result);
```

---

```
public class Hotel
{
    public int hotId;
    public string Name;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
}
```

Comment: I try it, but I get the same exception...Can be a some problem in e.Result?

Comment: @user1041802 I tried it with the json you posted and it works

Comment: @user1041802 I don't think it is installation problem. Make sure the definition of `Classes.RootObject` is equal to my `Hotel` (ie. maybe it is a class containing hotels?)

Comment: I founded the solution...the string in e.Result has an incorrect format (added '\\' between elements and before '[' was '"' and after ']' was '"'... i have to replace and remove this chars...                 string s = e.Result.Replace("\\","").Remove(0,1); s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);